# Command line interactive (python3.6.)

Tags: python-3.x, shell, command-line-interface

I love command line based programs and I want to make my personal program whit a command line interactive, that know where's the pointer and reacts accordingly to the program, I want to make buttons (not whit gui or tkinter) and some other things. i don't have any access to the curses lib because i have windows and i want to khnow if there's a way to do that (and maybye cross-platform)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am sorry to say that there is no way to do what you have asked for, but there is a way to print different text again in the same line, I think it might help.

```
print('\r'+"Whatever you want to write", end = '', flush = True)
```

This code overwrites whatever was previously written on that line, but you must make sure that when you printed the line before this, it was `end = ''`, because by default it is `end = '\n'` which adds a new line.

Also this code only overwrites the number of characters it has like...

Suppose you have used `print("Hello", end = '')`
Then you use `print('\r'+"Hi", end = '', flush = True)`

You will get...
`>>Hillo`

Also, this only works for CLI, not IDLE or Jupyter or IPython, I know that this method works on Windows, not sure about cross-platform

Comment: thank you very much. you helped me a lot. thanks. now it's time to try XD